# Set Jython standard indentation level for using in ant

Tags: python, ant, coding-style, jython, indentation

I am currently playing with jython embedded into an ant script, using the script task. It looks like this:

```
    <target name="start">
        <script language="jython">
            print self.getProject().getProperty("antpropertytest")
        </script>
    </target>
```

This however gives me an error as i used some tabs or spaces to intendant the python code so that it fits to the  intendation level. When i use the code below

```
    <target name="start">
        <script language="jython">
print self.getProject().getProperty("antpropertytest")
        </script>
    </target>
```

then it works fine but looks messed up. Is there any way to tell python to ignore the first X intendations of every line? Or is there another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

an extra `if 1:` is doing the trick:

> ```
> <target name="start">
>     <property name="antpropertytest" value="true"/>
>     <script language="jython">if 1:  # just for indentation
>         import sys
>
>         def example():
>             print "sys.path:\n    %s" % "\n    ".join(sys.path)
>             print "antpropertytest: %s" % self.getProject().getProperty("antpropertytest")
>
>         example()
>     </script>
> </target>
> ```